# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib

Saludos:

Soy bastante nuevo usando Python y estaba practicando con el siguiente problema:

Quería graficar el valor de la transferencia de calor a través de una placa de aluminio (traté de hacer lo más simple posible por el simple hecho de practicar cómo graficar resultados en python).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


span_L = []                           #Initialize span
span_Q = []
Q= []
Delta_T = 100                        #Assuming delta T = 100 C
T_cond = (207 /100)                  #Aluminum thermal conductivity W/(cm K)
Area = 1                             #Assuming Area is 1 cm^2


for lenght in range (100):         #Loop that appends different values
  span_L.append(float(lenght))

print("Lenght (L) in centimeters: ", span_L)     #Shows the output of values

for span_L in range (1,101):
  Q =  (T_cond*Area*Delta_T/span_L)
  span_Q.append(float(Q))

print(span_Q)

plt.plot(span_L,span_Q)
plt.title("Heat transfer for different thichkness values in an Al plate")
plt.xlabel("Lenght in cm")
plt.ylabel("Heat transfer in Watts [W]")
plt.show()
```

El problema que tengo es que me sale el error: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension` y al verificar el largo de ambas listas, ambas tienen la misma longitud.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el segundo ciclo `for`, cuando haces esto:

```
for span_L in range (1,101):
    ...
```

La lista `span_L` que has creado con anterioridad la reasignas como un entero cuyo valor varía durante el ciclo, quedando con un valor final de 100. Por eso, cuando intentas graficar `span_L` vs `span_Q` te manda justamente ese error.

Para solucionarlo, puedes utilizar una variable auxiliar en el ciclo `for`, algo como:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

span_L = []                           #Initialize span
span_Q = []
Q= []
Delta_T = 100                        #Assuming delta T = 100 C
T_cond = (207 /100)                  #Aluminum thermal conductivity W/(cm K)
Area = 1                             #Assuming Area is 1 cm^2

for lenght in range (100):         #Loop that appends different values
  span_L.append(float(lenght))

print("Length (L) in centimeters: ", span_L)     #Shows the output of values

for _span_L in range (1,101):
  Q =  (T_cond*Area*Delta_T/_span_L)
  span_Q.append(float(Q))

plt.plot(span_L,span_Q)
plt.title("Heat transfer for different thickness values in an Al plate")
plt.xlabel("Length in cm")
plt.ylabel("Heat transfer in Watts [W]")
plt.show()
```

Aunque, por lo que entiendo, creo que podrías ahorrarte el primer bucle y algunas definiciones iniciales de listas como la de Q o span_L.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

span_Q = []                           #Initialize span
Delta_T = 100                        #Assuming delta T = 100 C
T_cond = (207 /100)                  #Aluminum thermal conductivity W/(cm K)
Area = 1                             #Assuming Area is 1 cm^2

span_L = range(1,101)

print("Length (L) in centimeters: ", span_L)     #Shows the output of values

for L in span_L:
  Q =  (T_cond*Area*Delta_T/L)
  span_Q.append(float(Q))

plt.plot(span_L,span_Q)
plt.title("Heat transfer for different thickness values in an Al plate")
plt.xlabel("Length in cm")
plt.ylabel("Heat transfer in Watts [W]")
plt.show()
```

---

Ahora bien, a manera de recomendación, te sugeriría encarecidamente utilizar [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html) para definir vectores con los cuales podrás trabajar de manera más cómoda y eficiente, por ejemplo para tú caso, el código se reduciría a:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Delta_T = 100                        #Assuming delta T = 100 C
T_cond = (207/100)                  #Aluminum thermal conductivity W/(cm K)
Area = 1                             #Assuming Area is 1 cm^2

span_L = np.linspace(1,100)
span_Q = (T_cond*Area*Delta_T/span_L)

plt.plot(span_L,span_Q)
plt.title("Heat transfer for different thickness values in an Al plate")
plt.xlabel("Length in cm")
plt.ylabel("Heat transfer in Watts [W]")
plt.show()
```

Puedes consultar más información acerca de cómo trabajar con Matplotlib+Numpy en las [Scipy Lecture Notes](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/index.html).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! No sabía que me simplificaba tanto el codigo. Actualmente estoy aprendiendo python    debido a que ya hacia todos mis trabajos en matlab, no sabia que linspace tamvien funcionaba aqui.   Muchisimas gracias nuevamente!!!